# Python import modules: what is different between a file and a directory?

Tags: python, import, module

I have following files and directories in my project root directory

```
main.py
bar.py
foo \
    __init__.py
    alice.py
    bob.py
```

the files in directory **foo** are all empty files, and the content of **bar.py** is

```
alice = None
bob = None
```

and **main.py** is

```
import foo
import bar
print 'foo:', dir(foo)
print 'bar:', dir(bar)
```

When execute **python main.py** the output is

```
foo: ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
bar: ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'alice', 'bob']
```

Why there is no `alice` or `bob` in `foo`? And, what should I do other than

```
from foo import alice, bob
```

if I want to use `alice` and `bob` of the module `foo`, since there might be a lot of files in that folder?

**EDIT**

My question is not about the built-in function `dir` giving weird result. If I do this in **main.py**

```
import foo
foo.alice
```

An exception will occur: **AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'alice'**

There seems no `alice` in `foo`? I think I have some problem understanding how to import a directory as a module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It basically comes down to the difference between a module and a package.  From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html):

> Packages are a way of structuring Python’s module namespace by using “dotted module names”. For example, the module name A.B designates a submodule named B in a package named A. Just like the use of modules saves the authors of different modules from having to worry about each other’s global variable names, the use of dotted module names saves the authors of multi-module packages like NumPy or the Python Imaging Library from having to worry about each other’s module names.

The purpose of the `__init__.py` file within a directory is to make it a package.  This file provides a place specify the public facing interface for the package.  There's two ways you can get `alice` and `bob` into `foo`:

#### 1. Use `__all__`

In your `__init__.py` file, you can explicitly declare what modules you want to expose with `__all__`.  The following will expose `alice` and `bob`.

```
`__all__` = ['alice', bob']
```

#### 2. import `alice` and `bob` directly

Alternatively, importing the modules within the `__init__.py` file will also expose these modules.

It will also import these modules at initialization time, so whenever you import anything in foo they will also get imported.

Answer (score 3):

The `alice` and `bob` that you are seeing in `dir(bar)` are the variables from bar.py

```
dir(foo) doesn't mean directory.

dir : If called without an argument, return the names in the current scope.
Else, return an alphabetized list of names comprising (some of) the attributes
of the given object, and of attributes reachable from it.
If the object supplies a method named __dir__, it will be used; otherwise
the default dir() logic is used and returns
. for a module object: the module's attributes.
. for a class object:  its attributes, and recursively the attributes
    of its bases.
. for any other object: its attributes, its class's attributes, and
    recursively the attributes of its class's base classes.
```

In main.py write:

```
import foo.alice
import foo.bob
```

this should give you alice and bob

Comment: `import foo.bob` will give you `foo.bob`, not `bob`. `from foo import bob` gives you `bob`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# in foo/__init__.py:
__all__ = ['alice', 'bob']
```

would allow you to do this:

```
# in main.py
from foo import *
```

and import only those modules called out explicitly in **all**

Comment: Thanks. It works, but does it mean that each time I add a file to foo I should update __init__.py? :(

Comment: If you follow my answer, then yes.  There are ways you could get around this by inspecting the "foo" directory for *.py files and dynamically adding them to __all__ when the file is read... but that sounds like you're asking for trouble.

Comment: It's bad practice to do `from foo import *`.  Remember that part of the "Zen" of Python" is that "Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!"

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't automatically import modules of packages. It wants you to explicitly specify the name somewhere, either by using `from foo import alice` in `main.py`, or by having `foo/__init__.py` `import alice`, or by having `foo/__init__.py` include the `__all__` list.

My [answer on another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048518/importing-packages-in-python/9049246#9049246) goes into a bit more detail about why this is.