# In Python, why can't I do: import A; A.B.C.foo()

Tags: python, python-import

In other words, to use `foo` I need to import everything up to `foo` like:

```
from A.B.C import foo
```

or at most

```
from A.B import C
C.foo()
```

But I can't do:

```
from A import B
B.C.foo()
```

Which gives me something like `'module' object has no attribute "C"`.

Comment: Is B a folder and is there a __init\_\_.py file?

Comment: You *can* do what you want - if the module author structured their code in a way to allow it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing packages in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048518/importing-packages-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docs explain why: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

> Each module has its own private symbol table, which is used as the
>   global symbol table by all functions defined in the module. Thus, the
>   author of a module can use global variables in the module without
>   worrying about accidental clashes with a user’s global variables. On
>   the other hand, if you know what you are doing you can touch a
>   module’s global variables with the same notation used to refer to its
>   functions, modname.itemname.

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces:

> Strictly speaking, references to names in modules are attribute
>   references: in the expression modname.funcname, modname is a module
>   object and funcname is an attribute of it. In this case there happens
>   to be a straightforward mapping between the module’s attributes and
>   the global names defined in the module: they share the same namespace!

So simply B.C is not imported, and not known in the last example. 
But this will work:

```
from A import B.C
B.C.foo()
```