# Why do I have to write this import statement twice?

Tags: python, import, package

Here is my folder structure:

```
/ Thermal_Formatter
  Thermal_Formatter.py
  __init__.py

test.py
```

In `Thermal_Formatter.py` I have this method:

```
def processAndPrint(text):
```

in `test.py` this does NOT work:

```
import Thermal_Formatter
Thermal_Formatter.processAndPrint(something)
```

but this does:

```
import Thermal_Formatter.Thermal_Formatter
Thermal_Formatter.Thermal_Formatter.processAndPrint(something)
```

Why does it work when I write the module name twice, both in the import statement and the module call?

Comment: Because it's not a module name twice; you have a package and a module inside it with the same name.

Comment: write `from Thermal_Formatter import Thermal_Formatter` (Wooble is right about that part.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing packages in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048518/importing-packages-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `Thermal_Formatter` module is inside a package with same name. Try:

```
from Thermal_Formatter import Thermal_Formatter
Thermal_Formatter.processAndPrint(something)
```

If you want a more saner way to use it.