# Python can't import package

Tags: python, import, module, package

I have a package structure like:

```
thePackage/
    __init__.py
    moduleA.py
    moduleB.py
    moduleC.py
```

The `__init__.py` file contains

```
from . import moduleA
```

For simplicity I `cd` into the directory containing the foler `thePackage`.

When I try to `import thePackage` I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-10-5fe9a18b3124>", line 1, in <module>
import thePackage

  File "C:\thePackage\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from . import moduleA

ImportError: cannot import name 'moduleA'
```

I've read a few posts like 
[Importing packages in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048518/importing-packages-in-python), but still can't figure out my problem.  The accepted answer in that post suggests I should be able to import the submodule moduleA by `import thePackage.moduleA`, but when I try this I get the exact same error.

How can I important the package thePackage?

Also, how can I just import moduleA?

Answer (score 1):

```
from thePackage import moduleA
```

Comment: Your answer is correct for how to import the module of a package.  However, I had encountered a situation in which this method was failing.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the issue while using `Spyder` and `Python3.4`.

When I closed and restarted `Spyder`, I was able to import the package using `import thePackage`, and I was able to import moduleA using `import thePackage.moduleA`.

Also, originally when I first tried to import the module using `import thePackage`, it failed.  At this point I might have modified and saved the `__init__.py`.  Then I probably tried to import the module again using `import thePackage`, but maybe this doesn't always try to import the newly saved versions of `thePackage`.  Thus, I recommend trying

```
import importlib
importlib.reload(thePackage)
```

to force the import of the newly saved version of `thePackage`.

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
    sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

found it at https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/issues/368/module-object-has-no-attribute-packaging,
and it helped me when I was having challenges installing pyttsx,