# Importing classes in python returns cannot import name error

Tags: python, import, importerror

I'm starting out with my very first python project but I'm running into a problem right from the start. I'm trying to figure out how to import a class into my main.py file.

My directory structure is...

```
game
- __init__.py
- main.py
- player.py
```

So far I have in **main.py**...

```
from player import Player

player1 = Player("Ben")
print player1.name
```

I get the following error...

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>        File "main.py", line 1, in 
>         from player import Player
>       ImportError: cannot import name Player

I've had a google but can't find anything that works. Can someone help please?

I'm using Python 2.7.10

**Update**

So my player.py contains

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def name(self):
        return self.name
```

and my **init**.py file is empty

Comment: Show us the full contents of `player.py`.

Comment: show us what's in `__init__.py` and `player.py` for that matter.

Comment: Where are you invoking your script when you get the error? I would suspect `player.py` is not on the `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: what happens if you open ipython and try to import player?

Comment: Is that the only `player.py` file on your computer? It's possible that you're actually importing an older version of `player` that doesn't have a `Player` class.

Comment: From which directory are you trying to execute this?

Comment: @kev as far as i know it's the only player.py file, it's my first python script!

Comment: Works for me running both `python main.py` from the game directory and `python ./game/main.py`. Maybe your indentation in player.py is messed up and it isn't compiling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing packages in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048518/importing-packages-in-python)

Comment: Ah now this is weird, I just tried creating a new class and imported that just fine, I then tried the player file and it worked. Some kind of path caching thing?! I've got nothing else to explain that!

Comment: What IDE are you using? I think it has to do with the current directory when you initiate the script.

Comment: I'm using sublime, but i created the directory on the terminal, would that make a difference?

Comment: This code works fine even without the __init__.py. I just checked it on my system. Works fine! Though I am running the main.py from within the game folder.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `from player` Python looks for a module named `player` at the root of the PYTHONPATH. As no such module exists, an error is raised.

By using a relative import (prefixing the module name with a dot) you tell Python to look for the module in the same directory as the current file. Like this:

```
from .player import Player
```

Or, if that gets confusing, you can just use the absolute path (`game.player`) which should be at the root of the PYTHONPATH if installed correctly.

```
from game.player import Player
```

However, you can't always guarantee that a library will always be installed at the PYTHONPATH root by your users, so relative paths are generally preferred when importing modules within the same library. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) for more info.