# Cannot import class from module

Tags: python-3.x, import, module

I have 2 modules (StudentModel and Controller):

**StudentModel.py**

```py
    class Car:

       def __init__ (self, make, model, year, color):
            self.make = make
            self.model = model
            self.year = year
            self.color = color

        def drive(self):
            print("This car is driving")
        def stop(self):
            print("This car is stopping")
```

**Controller.py**

```py
    from StudentModel import Car
    
    car_1 = Car("Chevy", "Corvette", 2021, "blue")
    
    print(car_1.make)
    print(car_1.model)
    print(car_1.year)
    print(car_1.color)
```

When I run the program, an error occurs (Cannot import name "Car" from "StudentModel")

How I can solve it, please...

[StudentModel.py screenshot with errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSD44.png)
[Controller.py screenshot with errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HipWI.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing classes in python returns cannot import name error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33133143/importing-classes-in-python-returns-cannot-import-name-error)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a path issue, You can try adding an empty `__init__.py` file to the directory otherwise you'll have to add `from . import StudentModel` to it.