# ModuleNotFoundError on submodule

Tags: python, python-import

I realize that questions like this have been asked thousands and thousands of times, but I cannot figure out how to successfully import my `data` submodule.

#### MCVE

Directory structure

```
┌ dummy
├── setup.py
└─┬ dummy
  ├── __init__.py
  ├── foo.py
  └─┬ data
    ├── __init__.py
    └── data_bar.py
```

My top-level `__init__.py` contains

```py
from .foo import *
from .data import *
```

and `data/__init__.py` is empty.

---

#### Recreate the problem

I pip install the package to a fresh virtual environment

```
pip install /path/to/dummy
```

which works fine. Then in an ipython shell **run from a completely directory**, I try importing the package

```py
H:\Desktop$ ipython
In [1]: import dummy
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-cfc16ef2ccc8> in <module>
----> 1 import dummy

C:\Users\rlane\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\secdetect_test\lib\site-packages\dummy\__init__.py in <module>
      1 from .foo import *
----> 2 from .data import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dummy.data'
```

`foo.py` imports without error, but after trying every conceivable variation of `from .data import *` I cannot get the code in the `data` submodule to load.

---

#### Things I've tried

Variations within top-level `__init__.py`

```py
from .data import *
from data import *
from . import data
from .data import data_bar
from .data.data_bar import *
```

All of which result in the same `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `dummy.data` is missing as a package in the `setup.py` script.

```py
setup(
    name=DISTNAME,
    author=MAINTAINER,
    ...
    packages=[
        'dummy',
        'dummy.data'
    ],
    ...
    long_description=open('README.md').read(),
)
```

With this configuration, `from .data import *`, and `from . import data` in the top-level `__init__.py` both work.

Comment: If this is the preferred answer go ahead and accept it so this doesn't stay open. It is okay to accept your own answer! I'll give it an upvote since it seems to answer the question adequately.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same, but it worked for me.

This is my structure(note that all these files are in a folder called *dummy*).

[image]

Python files:

foo.py:

```
def foo_module():
    return 'foo module'
```

data_bar.py:

```
def data_bar_module():
    return 'Data bar'
```

test.py:

```
import dummy
#from dummy.data import data_bar

#print(dummy.foo.foo_module())
#print(data_bar.data_bar_module())
```

When I do `python3 test.py` it gives me no errors and when I uncomment the commented lines in `test.py` file it gives:

```
foo module
Data bar
```

I am not exactly sure why it does work, but try to import data package like this, it may work.

```
from dummy.data import *
```

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: You may also want to see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048518/importing-packages-in-python)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it turned out that the problem was actually with my `setup.py` script and not the `__init__.py` files or organization.