# Create namespace | Extend name tree at file level

Tags: python, namespaces, python-packaging

For example, in `C++` we can write

```
namespace MilkyWay{
    namespace AlphaCentauri {
        int Planets = 4;
    }
    namespace SolarSys {
        int Planets = 8;
    }
}
```

And then use it as `MilkyWay::SolarSys::Planets`

Is there a way to write something like `namespace` in `C++`? Or in other words is there a possibility to extend name tree not only at the level of folder nesting but also at the level of a single file?

Or. Suppose we have the following structure:

```
sound/                          Top-level package
  __init__.py               Initialize the sound package
  formats/                  Subpackage for file format conversions
          __init__.py
          wavread.py
          wavwrite.py
          ...
  effects/                  Subpackage for sound effects
          __init__.py
          echo.py
          surround.py
          ...
  filters/                  Subpackage for filters
          __init__.py
          equalizer.py
          vocoder.py
          ...
```

I can do `from sound.formats import wavread` but why I can not do `from sound import formats`?

Comment: I think this will help you : [python package](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-create-a-python-package/)

Comment: *"why I can not do `from sound import formats`?"* — But you _can_!?

Comment: And no, C++-like namespaces do not exist in Python. The existing organisation mechanisms (folders/files/classes) are typically perfectly sufficient and—personally speaking—I have never felt a need for anything more.

Comment: @deceze I can, but then `formats.wavread.do_smth()` raises: `AttributeError: module 'formats' has no attribute 'wavread'`. While `from sound.formats import wavread`;`wavread.do_smth()` works fine

Comment: Yes, `from sound import formats` basically just loads `sound/formats/__init__.py`, not every single file within that folder. The typical idiom here is to reexport the module with `from . import wavread` inside that `__init__.py`, so it does become an attribute of the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, my question is similar to [Importing packages in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048518/importing-packages-in-python)

The deal is

> However, having found the package directory, it does not then scan that directory and automatically import all .py files.

So, to get this work we need add to the `__init__.py` needed submodules (`.py` files), so that python will import it.

For example file `sound/formats/__init__.py` must contain

```
from . import wavread, wavwrite
```

And now

```
from sound import formats

formats.wavread.do_smth()
```

Will work fine

Thanks to [@deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze)